# EKS fargate cluster with loadbalancer service - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (port 80) + ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED (port 443), logs on pod not showing requests

Tags: kubernetes, networking, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, openresty

i create a cluster:

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name example-cluster \
--region eu-central-1 \
--fargate \
--instance-types=t2.medium \
--full-ecr-access \
```

i update the kubeconfig:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-central-1 --name example-cluster
```

i use my kubernetes.yaml:

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml:

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: openresty-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: openresty
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: openresty
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: openresty
        image: 463865334882.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/commit-fargate-openresty:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: openresty-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: openresty
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: LoadBalancer
```

pod and service are ok:

```
k get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
openresty-deployment-84d55495bb-qml2r   1/1     Running   0          47m
```

services:

```
kubectl get services
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                                                  PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes          ClusterIP      10.100.0.1     <none>                                                                       443/TCP                      63m
openresty-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.57.29   aa5d9fcea02554a4999954064d111335-1488746410.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:31331/TCP,443:32027/TCP   47m
```

logs on pod not showing any attempts to the container:

```
kubectl logs openresty-deployment-84d55495bb-qml2r
2024/03/07 08:04:36 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

for port 443 i get ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

for port 80 i get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

anyone has ideas?